# Create roles-tree for Postgre database with cascade privileges

Tags: sql, postgresql, roles, postgresql-9.5

How can I create correct roles-tree for postgresql database for users which can do this:

- read only (select) data (**A**)
- A + modify (insert, delete, update) data (**B**)
- B + create tables (**C**)
- C + create tables and also all special privileges (**D**)

I checked documentation about [roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html) and [default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), but nothing helps me understand how Postgres work with roles. My actual script for create **sample roles**:

```
create database daba;

create role "ra" nologin noinherit; -- default read only role
grant connect on database "daba" to "ra";
grant usage on schema public to "ra" with grant option;
grant select on all tables in schema public to "ra" with grant option;
-- ingore sequences and functions now

create role "rb" nologin inherit;
grant "ra" to "rb"; -- grant connect, grant select
grant insert, update, delete on all tables in schema public to "rb" with grant option;

create role "rc" nologin inherit;
grant "rb" to "rc";
grant all privileges on schema public to "rc" with grant option;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to "rc" with grant option;

create role "rd" nologin inherit;
grant "rc" to "rd";
grant "postgres" to "rd";

-- default privileges for new created tables
-- only "rc" and "rd" can create table, "ra" can read it
alter default privileges for role "rc", "rd" in schema public grant select on tables to "ra" with grant option;
-- "rb" and higher can insert, update or delete also
alter default privileges for role "rc", "rd" in schema public grant insert, update, delete on tables to "rb" with grant option;

-- roles done, create users
create role "ua" login encrypted password 'ua' in role "ra";
create role "ub" login encrypted password 'ub' in role "rb";
create role "uc" login encrypted password 'uc' in role "rc";
create role "ud" login encrypted password 'ud' in role "rd";
```

OK, roles and users are created, now test with **errors** on lines:

```
-- connect as "ud"
create table ud_a (a numeric); -- OK
insert into ud_a values (1); -- OK
select * from ud_a; -- OK -- 1 row

-- connect as "uc"
select * from ud_a; -- SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation ud_a

-- As user "uc" I cannot insert value, or drop table
insert into ud_a values (2); -- **SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation ud_a**
drop table ud_a; -- **SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: must be owner of relation ud_a**

-- But I can create new table! As "uc":
create table uc_a (a numeric); -- OK
insert into uc_a values (2); -- OK

-- After this when i connect as more powerfull user - "ud"
-- I cannot even read from this table even though my user "ud" is created under role "rd" with "grant 'rc' to 'rd'":
select * from uc_a; -- SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation uc_a

-- Connect as "ua" for read only return also errors for selects:
select * from ud_a; -- SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation ud_a
select * from uc_a; -- SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation uc_a
```

Cleaning:

```
-- as "postgres":
drop owned by "ud"; drop owned by "uc"; drop owned by "ub"; drop owned by "ua";
drop role "ud"; drop role "uc"; drop role "ub"; drop role "ua";
drop owned by "rd"; drop owned by "rc"; drop owned by "rb"; drop owned by "ra";
drop role "rd"; drop role "rc"; drop role "rb"; drop role "ra";
drop database daba;
```

I need to create role structure where user A can select all tables created by user C or D and all users inherit from prveious level (so everything which can select user A can select also user B, C and D) and also role D which can drop table created by user under role C and so on...

Can you help me with this?